# Localized month name in Python

Tags: python, localization

I'd like to have localized months name automatically given by Python.

I use this piece of code : `datetime.datetime.strptime(j, "%m").strftime("%B")` where j is the month number.

My problem is that it keeps giving me "January" while I'm expecting "Janvier" (french locale).

I tried to play a little with locale and the only way I found to make it work is to call `locale.set_locale(locale.LC_ALL, "")` at the begining of the script.

Is it the good way to go ? Or is there any problem and nicer solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: Seeing that the Python Docs give `%B` as the `Locale's Month Name`, setting the locale should be a good way to do this!

Comment: Yes, calling `locale.set_locale()` is a good way to set the default locale.

Comment: Ok, i'll go with it. I thought Python set the locale automatically, without needing to tell it to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your locale set at the OS level,

```
locale.set_locale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print locale.nl_langinfo(locale.LC_MON1)

"janvier"
```

Or you can set it at python level:

```
 locale.set_locale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')
 print locale.nl_langinfo(locale.LC_MON1)

 "janvier"
```

Comment: On my system it's `locale.MON_1` (python 2.7.3)

Comment: In Python 3 it is `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` (Python 3.7).

Answer (score 7):

If you only wan't it to affect the datetime function try this:

```
def getLocalizedMonth(j):
  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
  datetime.datetime.strptime(j, "%m").strftime("%B")
  locale.setlocale(locale.getdefaultlocale())
```

And yes I think using the locale.setlocale is the best solution!

Comment: `locale.setlocale` has 2 arguments. In your case should be: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale.getdefaultlocale())`